# If $ f:G \to H $ is a homomorphism between groups $ G$ and $ H $ and if $ X \subseteq G $ then $ f (\langle X \rangle) = \langle f (X) \rangle $.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\langle X \rangle$ denote the subgroup generated by $ X. $ If $f: G \to H$ is a homomorphism between groups $G$ and $H$ and if $ X \subseteq G $ then $ f (\langle X \rangle) = \langle f (X) \rangle$.

How do I use the homomorphism property to prove this with subgroups? I've only been introduced to the definition that is defined for elements $ a, b \in G $ such that $ f(ab) = f (a) f (b). $ Would I just elements  $a, b \in \langle X \rangle$ instead?

Comment: Use that $\langle X\rangle= \{x_1x_2\ldots x_k\mid k\geq 0,\,x_i\in X\mbox{ or }x_i^{-1}\in X\mbox{ for all }1\leq i\leq k\}$ and similar for $\langle f(X)\rangle$.

Comment: How do I use this with the homomorphism property? I know that every element of $\langle X \rangle $ will have that form but I do not know how use that with the homomorphism

Comment: Ok. Set $a=x_1x_2\ldots x_k\in\langle X\rangle$. If $x_i\in X$, then $f(x_i)\in f(X)$; if $x_{i}^{-1}\in X$, then $f(x_i)=f((x_i^{-1})^{-1})= f(x_i^{-1})^{-1}$ is an inverse of element in $f(X)$, hence is in $\langle f(X)\rangle$. Now $f(a)= f(x_1)f(x_2)\ldots f(x_k)\in\langle f(X)\rangle$. This proves $\subseteq$. The part $\supseteq$ is very similar.

Comment: Note that $\langle X\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $X$, and $\langle f(X)\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $H$ containing $f(X)$. Now, note that $f(\langle X\rangle)$ is a subgroup of $H$ containing $f(X)$, hence $f(\langle X\rangle)\supseteq \langle f(X)\rangle$, since $\langle f(X)\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $f(X)$. Also $f^{-1}(\langle f(X)\rangle)$ is a subgroup containing $X$, hence $f^{-1}(\langle f(X)\rangle)\supseteq \langle X\rangle$, hence $f(\langle X\rangle)\subseteq f(f^{-1}(\langle f(X)\rangle))\subseteq \langle f(X)\rangle$

Comment: Thanks, the problem is much more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X\subset \left\langle X\right\rangle$, $f(X) \subseteq f(\left\langle X\right\rangle)$ and thus $\left\langle f(X)\right\rangle \subset f(\left\langle X\right\rangle)$. Let $J$ be any subgroup of $H$ which contains $f(X)$. Since $f$ is a homomoprhism, $f^{-1}(J)$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $X$, which implies $f^{-1}(J)$ contains $\left\langle X\right\rangle$. Therefore, $J$ contains $f(\left\langle X\right\rangle)$. Since $\left\langle f(X)\right\rangle$ is itself a subgroup of $H$ which contains $f(X)$, we obtain the reverse inclusion $\left\langle f(X)\right\rangle \supseteq f(\left\langle X\right\rangle)$. Therefore, $f(\left\langle X\right\rangle) = \left\langle f(X)\right\rangle$.