# Let $f:G \to H$ be surjective group homomorphism. Show that if $G=\langle a \rangle$, then $H=\langle f(a) \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $f:G \to H$ be surjective group homomorphism. Show that if $G=\langle a \rangle$, then $H=\langle f(a)\rangle$

Homorphism means $f(a*a)=f(a)*f(a)$

onto means $$\forall h \in H, \exists g \in G : f(g)=h $$

$H=\langle f(a)\rangle \Leftrightarrow H \subset \langle f(a)\rangle, 
\langle f(a)\rangle \subset H$

> Assume $G=\langle a\rangle$
>
> **$\Rightarrow$ (if $h \in H$ is $h \in \langle f(a)\rangle$?)**
>
> $h \in H$ so $\exists g \in G$ such that $f(g)=h$ and $g\in \langle a \rangle$ so $\exists  k 
> \in Z$ s.t $f(a^k)=f(a)^k=h$ so $h\in \langle f(a)\rangle$
>
> **$\Leftarrow$ Showing $\langle f(a)\rangle \subset H$)**
>
> let $x\in \langle f(a)\rangle $ so $\exists k ...$ $f(a)^k=x$ so $f(a^k)=x$ and $a^k \in G$  that is $f(a^k)\in H$

Critique?

Comment: The second step doesn't require any proof : $\langle f(a)\rangle \subset H$ holds by definition. You might also be interested in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123005/if-fg-to-h-is-a-homomorphism-between-groups-g-and-h-and-if-x-sub?rq=1

Comment: Symbolic notation is succinct but at the cost of readability. To make your proof easier to digest use words instead of symbols where you can so that the idea in the proof is transparent to the reader. You'll find it also helps you figure out if the proof is correct for yourself since it's easier to read and follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of your proof is correct. Good job. :) As said in the comments though, the bit about proving that $\langle f(a) \rangle \subset H$ is unnecessary. I suppose you can write it down if you want, but it's kinda "*obviously true*": $H$ is the codomain of the map, so $f(a) \in H$, and since $H$ is a group any power of $f(a)$ must be in there too.

In line with what users are saying in the comments, my critiques are about language/grammar. A major thing to remark on is that your proof *looks like* some math symbols with a few conjunction words thrown in. First and foremost, a proof should be a collection of sentences. Sentences that are grammatically correct, and that give your proof a sense of flow. Remember that your proof is meant to be read and understood by a person, and not just some grading robot looking for correctness ;) . I might write-up the same proof like this:

> Assume $G=\langle a \rangle$, and consider some $h \in H$. Since $f$ is surjective, there must be some $g \in G$ such that $f(g)=h$. The group $G$ is generated by $a$, so there must be some integer power $k$ such that $g=a^k$. But $f$ is a homomorphism, so we have $$h = f(g) = f(a^k)=f(a)^k\,,$$ so $h\in \langle f(a)\rangle\,.$ That is to say, a general element $h \in H$ is a power of $f(a)$, so $H = \langle f(a) \rangle$.

Replacing certain mathematical symbols in lieu of their English language counterpart is often a good idea to help the readability of a proof.